# Ubuntu installation does not detect Windows 7

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows

I was trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 with an installed Windows 7.  I was following all steps on page, but it just simply does not gives me option to click Install them by side. It just tells that **there were no OS detected**. After that I ran boot-repair and received the following log:

```
 Boot Info Script 0.61.full + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info September 18th 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121126 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1 4,294,967,295 4,294,967,295  ee GPT

/dev/sda1 ends after the last sector of /dev/sda

GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048       206,847       204,800 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2         206,848       468,991       262,144 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
/dev/sda3         468,992 1,228,802,047 1,228,333,056 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda4   1,228,802,048 1,953,523,711   724,721,664 Data partition (Windows/Linux)

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        F41C-5F8A                              vfat       
/dev/sda3        44CEB0FBCEB0E678                       ntfs       
/dev/sda4        CED8B435D8B41E21                       ntfs       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sr0         /live/image              iso9660    (ro,noatime)


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

File descriptor 7 (pipe:[5456]) leaked on lvscan invocation. Parent PID 7672: bash
File descriptor 8 (pipe:[5456]) leaked on lvscan invocation. Parent PID 7672: bash
  No volume groups found
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 2012-10-07__12h13 ===================
boot-repair version : 3.193-0ppa22~lucid
boot-sav version : 3.193-0ppa39~lucid
glade2script-gtk2 version : 0.0.1-0ppa4~lucid
boot-sav-nonfree version :
Please connect internet. Then close this window.
/usr/share/boot-sav/gui-update.sh: line 77: add-apt-repository: command not found
/usr/share/boot-sav/gui-update.sh: line 77: add-apt-repository: command not found
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/os-uninstaller/ubuntu lucid main
/usr/share/boot-sav/gui-update.sh: line 77: add-apt-repository: command not found
/usr/share/boot-sav/gui-update.sh: line 77: add-apt-repository: command not found
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu lucid main
W: Failed to fetch http://cdn.debian.net/debian/dists/squeeze/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'cdn.debian.net'

W: Failed to fetch http://cdn.debian.net/debian/dists/squeeze/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Could not resolve 'cdn.debian.net'

W: Failed to fetch http://cdn.debian.net/debian/dists/squeeze/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'cdn.debian.net'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/squeeze/updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/squeeze/updates/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/squeeze/updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://cdn.debian.net/debian/dists/squeeze-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'cdn.debian.net'

W: Failed to fetch http://cdn.debian.net/debian/dists/squeeze-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Could not resolve 'cdn.debian.net'

W: Failed to fetch http://cdn.debian.net/debian/dists/squeeze-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'cdn.debian.net'

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/os-uninstaller/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/os-uninstaller/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/os-uninstaller/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'

W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 63 not upgraded.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
os-uninstaller
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/os-uninstaller/ubuntu/ lucid/main os-uninstaller all 3.18-0ppa13~lucid
Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/os-uninstaller/ubuntu/pool/main/o/os-uninstaller/os-uninstaller_3.18-0ppa13~lucid_all.deb  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
E: Some files failed to download

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 63 not upgraded.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
boot-repair
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ lucid/main boot-repair all 3.193-0ppa22~lucid
Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/pool/main/b/boot-repair/boot-repair_3.193-0ppa22~lucid_all.deb  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
E: Some files failed to download
File descriptor 7 (pipe:[5456]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 3520: /bin/sh
File descriptor 8 (pipe:[5456]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 3520: /bin/sh
No volume groups found
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Boot-Repair-Disk 18.07.2012, squeeze, Debian, x86_64)
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
initrd=/live/initrd2.img boot=live config   quiet BOOT_IMAGE=/live/vmlinuz2

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


=================== os-prober:


=================== blkid:
/dev/sda1: UUID="F41C-5F8A" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/sda3: UUID="44CEB0FBCEB0E678" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda4: UUID="CED8B435D8B41E21" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"

Windows not detected by os-prober on sda3.

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util sfdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Presence of EFI/Microsoft file detected: /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Presence of EFI/Microsoft file detected: /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi
Presence of EFI/Boot file detected: /mnt/boot-sav/sda1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
Please report this message to yannubuntu@gmail.com
=================== dmesg | grep EFI :
BIOS is EFI-compatible, and maybe setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.


=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:
sda1    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  is-correct-EFI, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   not-far,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda1.
sda3    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda3.
sda4    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda4.

sda : GPT,  no-BIOS_boot,   has-correctEFI,     not-usb,    has-os, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes


=================== parted -l:

Model: ATA ST1000LM024 HN-M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size   File system  Name                          Flags
1      1049kB  106MB   105MB  fat32        EFI system partition          boot
2      106MB   240MB   134MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
3      240MB   629GB   629GB  ntfs         Basic data partition
4      629GB   1000GB  371GB  ntfs         Basic data partition




Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label

=================== parted -lm:

BYT;
/dev/sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA ST1000LM024 HN-M;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot;
2:106MB:240MB:134MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:240MB:629GB:629GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:;
4:629GB:1000GB:371GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:;



Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label


=================== mount:
aufs on / type aufs (rw)
tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/sr0 on /live/image type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
tmpfs on /live/cow type tmpfs (rw,noatime,mode=755)
tmpfs on /live type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 type vfat (rw)
/dev/sda3 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda3 type fuseblk (rw,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda4 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda4 type fuseblk (rw,allow_other,blksize=4096)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/sda (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sr0 (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom cdrw char console core cpu_dma_latency disk dvd dvdrw fd full fuse hidraw0 hidraw1 hidraw2 hidraw3 hidraw4 hpet initctl input kmsg log MAKEDEV mcelog md mem net network_latency network_throughput null port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 scd0 sda sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sg0 sg1 shm snapshot sr0 stderr stdin stdout urandom usb v4l vga_arbiter video0 xconsole zero
ls /dev/md:
ls /mnt/boot-sav/sda3: Windows Users temp Information Volume System Games Riot $Recycle.Bin Recovery (x86) Files Program Files Program ProgramData PerfLogs pagefile.sys NVIDIA MSOCache msdia80.dll Intel hiberfil.sys eclipse Settings and Documents Config.Msi bdr-ld01.mbr bdr-ld01 bdr-im01.gz bdr-cf01 bdr-bz01 bdlog.txt

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


=================== df -Th:

Filesystem    Type    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
aufs          aufs    3.9G  8.3M  3.9G   1% /
tmpfs        tmpfs    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /lib/init/rw
udev         tmpfs    3.9G  176K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs        tmpfs    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sr0   iso9660    339M  339M     0 100% /live/image
tmpfs        tmpfs    3.9G  8.3M  3.9G   1% /live/cow
tmpfs        tmpfs    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /live
tmpfs        tmpfs    3.9G  8.0K  3.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1     vfat     96M   18M   79M  19% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda3  fuseblk    586G  140G  447G  24% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sda4  fuseblk    346G  176M  346G   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda4

=================== fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121126 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16128 * 512 = 8257536 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3ffc3ff

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1      266306  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


EFI detected. Please check the options.

=================== Default settings
Recommended-Repair
This setting would reinstall the  of .
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s   fix-windows-boot

=================== Settings chosen by the user
Boot-Info
This setting will not act on the MBR.



No change has been performed on your computer. See you soon!
Please connect internet. Then close this window.
```

I would realy need help because I urgently need Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried using the manual partitioner? [It's the Something Else option]. You can alternatively install in VirtualBox.

Comment: Yes i was checking this Something else but, this installs it on 2 partions, thath why i would realy like to use option Install them by side.

Comment: Installing side by side would also install on two partitions.

Comment: Nasty - Windows is using all four logical partitions on the drive.  It has also got the efi partition.  To make an extended partition to put Ubuntu on, one of the partitions must be deleted.  I've seen advice which recommends removing the efi partition but I have no experience so I'm going to sit back and watch this one myself.

Comment: You can use Wubi. It uses a disk image inside the Windows partition to do a full boot(not a VM) and you can pick via the Windows bootloader. I'll write an answer right now.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to solve your problem:

### **Wubi**

Wubi is not enabled on the CD, so you need to download [wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/pre-download?destination=desktop&distro=wubi&release=&bits=) and save it to a folder on your computer, say your desktop. Then, copy [or download if you don't have it] the Ubuntu ISO image for the version and architecture you want. Keep the file named *as-is*, and put  it in the same folder as the `wubi.exe` file you downloaded. Run that `wubi.exe`. It may complain:

> No disk in drive

but click Continue on it a few hundred :) times to get to the correct screen. You can set your username/password/installation size, and use Ubuntu as the desktop environment.

Click the button to proceed and then reboot when prompted. Two reboots(Windows->Ubuntu installer on your HDD->Ubuntu [fully functional]) will be needed, and you will be prompted when you need to reboot.

### VirtualBox

You can also install in VirtualBox using the default settings for everything, (both on the Ubuntu side and the VirtualBox side). I recommend the Ubuntu alternate CD for this one. You can then go to additional drivers and install the VirtualBox guest additions, and then *without removing them*, install the built-in ones with <kbd>Right control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. This hasn't caused Apt issues for me, and it helps alleviate the failure to install directly from the CD.

Comment: Is this WUBI some kind of virtualization or what?

Comment: @ArcaneWater Wubi is not. It has a disk image but when you bot into Wubi, you actually load GRUB from a file, which is configured to mount the disk image and run Ubuntu exclusively, without any virtualization software.

Answer (score 0):

## Common partition table for dual-booting:

This works for most.

Partition 01 **(Primary)**

- This is your C:\ in Windows, formatted in NTFS.

Partition 02

- A small system reserved partition (100MB) automatically generated by Windows.

Partition 03 **(Primary)**

- Linux root partition used as "/", formatted from Ext4

Partition 04

- Around 4GB partition used as "SWAP"

Comment: In the comments, it is evident there are already 4 primary partitions.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions:

1. During installation set Windows partition to mount e.g. in /windows
2. After installation mount windows partition and run:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Hope it helped.

Comment: How should i do the 2. option? mount windows partition and run sudo update-grub?